# CORS issue? - Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I am facing the frequent 405 problem when launching a POST request from my localhost:8080 to an external API. I've tried to use many different options but I don´t get the key of the problem.

```
URL = api end point;  //Your URL
var datajson = '{'
   +'"image" : "'+imageBase64+'"'
   +'}';
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var body = JSON.parse(datajson)

   if ('withCredentials' in req) {
       req.open('POST', URL, true);
       req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       req.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(req);
       req.send(body);
   }
```

The error I get in browser is:

> OPTIONS http://blablabla 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>   sendToBioFace @ myjavascript.js:38
>   send @ myjavascript.js:56
>   onclick @ (index):13
>   (index):1 Failed to load http://blablabla: Response for preflight has invalid  HTTP status code 405

Find below the Headers:

```
Request URL:http://blablabla.com
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: destinationip:16111
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Allow:POST
Content-Length:1569
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 28 Jan 2018 19:13:42 GMT
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host: destinationip:16111
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I do not see "method" in your request headers?

Comment: It's a problem on the remote `blablabla` side. Contact their support team and check their documentation to ensure you're following it right.

Comment: Whenever you send CORS requests to the remote API with a payload, the browser will send an OPTIONS request, which has to return status 200 and the three header values `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Request-Method`. The browser will then check your CORS request against these values and only send it if the values and your request match. Obviously, the remote API does not allow OPTIONS requests, so you cannot call their JSON endpoints from your domains. Without knowing which remote API you are using, we cannot give you any more advice than that.

Comment: Doing a request either from Postman or a python script... it works.

Comment: @JorgeGarciaDominguez that's because CORS is designed for browsers. Postman and your python script do not and should not respect it.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to send cross domain request but the headers that you sent doesn't include OPTIONS.

You should add OPTIONS request header to your outgoing requests.

Comment: Could you elaborate (with exact examples of headers and references to the specs/docs)? At this moment the whole answer does not make much sense.

Comment: There are 2 headers that you have to specify for a request like this.

1. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
2. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers :Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept`

Comment: Any chance you provide the exact values and a reference to the spec? I'm not aware of anything special, CORS worked just like that without any problems.

Comment: And they **ARE** in the response. You do not put it in the request.

Comment: Please apologize me, but I don´t understand your suggestion. Should I set any request header? Should I provide more information?